# Xcode UI tests: how to identify a custom view with no static text?

Tags: ios, xcode7, nib, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I need to implement an UI test to check that certain custom view is shown within another view. I am not using `storyboard`, but separated `nib` files, and such custom subview has no static text to identify it. I have checked the `XCUIElementQuery` API and I've seen it provides the funcs `matching(identifier: String)` and `matching(_ elementType: XCUIElementType, identifier: String?)`, but, since I am only using separated `nib` files, I am not sure which `identifier` is this and how should I set it.

Answer (score 3):

You can set an accessibility identifier of xib element: [image]